# binding doesn't create text

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint, unreal-umg

I'm trying to set up a hi score table in my game and the binding to get the score isn't being called at all. It isn't working. It uses the same logic as the names, but doesn't display anything in the text box. binding the name function to the cell prints the hi score name fine, so I think it's a problem with int to text.

[Blueprint Snips](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NutZf.jpg)

thanks

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem using the information in the question. Please see [mre] for help on how to make the problem reproducible.

Comment: thank you @Ruzihm for your interest in helping me find a solution to my problem, but I have already solved this issue. next time I'll provide you personally with the problem isolated in a ue4 project for your inspection :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I haven't found a direct answer to my original question, but this tutorial is a much better starting point for a hi score table

[YouTube : Tefel Dev : Unreal Engine 4 Guide - Scoreboard](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZseexEWWOJg)